# enable insecure websocket in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, websocket

I have an https:// web app that is opening an insecure websocket connection.
By default browsers disallow this, but I can bypass behaviour in FireFox with network.websocket.allowInsecureFromHTTPS = true

Is there a similar setting for chrome ? How can I force chrome to open ws:// connection from https:// webapp ?
Starting chrome with extra flags is not ideal, because this would be impossible on mobile devices ?